# T-SQL, select into

Tags: sql-server

In the SQL Server, how to select multiple values into a temp table ?

for example, I want to put 'A' , 'B' into #tmp table, how to do it ?

```
select 'A'
union
select 'B'
into #tmp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the "Into" on the first select, plus, if you are really doing literals, then you must give it a label for the column name.

```
Select 'A' As 'Label'
Into #tmp
Union
Select 'B'
```

Comment: But I recommend against using `'single quotes'` for aliases. Some forms of that syntax are deprecated, and when mixed with actual string literals, it can be extremely confusing for those who didn't write the code. I prefer `[square brackets]` but my first choice would be using an alias/column name that doesn't require delimiters at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand. That's interesting, (this old dog is pretty slow to change). What I CAN tell you is that 1) It _still_ works in SQL 2012 without complaining. 2) SQL 2012 docs *only* mention square brackets. 3) Apparently neither is ANSI! double quotes are! (third hand, mind you https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125027/unclear-deprecation-of-column-alias-in-select-list)

Comment: Deprecated does not mean "stopped working" - I did not say the code would break in SQL Server 2012. Certain variations might in the future. [Lots of dialog about alias convention here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases), but [the official documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016) (search for "string_alias"). The one you used here is not on the list (yet), but that doesn't make it more readable or less prone to being misconstrued.

Comment: So, I did some more poking around and found the ANSI-92 standard (http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and yes, it appears the correct way is to use either *double quotes* (which is the way you quote identifiers in SQL--and can *never* be used for strings), or to a lesser extent, it can be a string, that is single quotes. I may be wrong about the using the string (from an ANSI standpoint), but if you look on page 87, points #13 & 14 seem to say to me, that if the parser changes a quote (') to a double quote ("), then the identifier can be matched.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks for the MSDN reference to the deprecated items in SQL 2012.  Good to know.

Comment: I fail to see why, regardless of whether it is legal or not, you'd want to ever use a confusing string delimiter (`'` or `"`) for a column or alias. Why impair readability when `[square brackets]`  could never cause an alias to be confused for a string literal? I realize that this convention adheres to SQL Server's standard and not ANSI's, but when in Rome...

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it as a subquery (or a CTE)

```
select * into #tmp
from
(
    select col='A'
    union select col='B'
) sub
```

Comment: I find this cleaner and more intuitive than @Jim's. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert #tmp (yourcol)
  select 'A' union 
  select 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into #tmp
select 'A'
union
Select 'B'
```

Comment: With this you have to explicitly create the table.